# ngclass conditions in angular 2 with multipal classes

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ngclass for set class upon specific condition.

I tried:

```
 [ngClass]="{'warnColor gray1':alerts[0].error==0,'warnColor red':alerts[0].error!=0}"
```

but strangely when left condition is apply only gray is printed into the span.

so the span look like this

```
<span class="gray1" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></span>
```

I know I can use  else condtion(?:) but what is wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Regarding the syntax, it is correct. Can you also describe how alerts look like?

Comment: Have you tried `[ngClass]="{'warnColor gray1':alerts[0].error==0,'warnColor':alerts[0].error!=0, 'red':alerts[0].error!=0}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[ngClass]="{'warnColor gray1': alerts[0].error == 0, 'warnColor red': alerts[0].error != 0}"` the `ngClass` directive is called. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts) for reference.

```
private _toggleClass(klass: string, enabled: any): void {
    klass = klass.trim();
    if (klass) {
        klass.split(/\s+/g).forEach( klass => { this._renderer.setElementClass(this._ngEl.nativeElement, klass, !!enabled); });
    }
}
```

The `_toggleClass` method of the directive actually removes and sets the classes on the element. In your case it is called two times.

First time:
`klass` is `warnColor gray1`, `enabled` is `true` as the condition is true

This sets two classes on your element, if set a breakpoint in `_toggleClass` method you can see that actually both `warnColor` and `gray1` classes are applied to the element.

Second time:
`klass` is `warnColor red`, `enabled` is `false` as the condition evaluates to false

This removes two classes from your element namely `warnColor` and `red`, now `warnColor` class was applied in first step but now it has been removed so at the end you wind up only having class `gray1`.

So instead I recommend this syntax for common classes:

```
<div class="warnColor" [ngClass]="{'gray1': alerts[0].error == 0, 'red': alerts[0].error != 0}">
    Some html
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working with ternary operator

```
<span [ngClass]="alerts[0].error == 0 ? 'warnColor gray1' : 'warnColor red'"></span>
```

I do not know why your syntax is not working, it seems to be correct. Angular seems to be doing something in the back, maybe they try to format camelCase to something else because changing `warnColor` to `warn-color` makes your syntax work

```
[ngClass]="{'warn-color gray1':alerts[0].error==0,'warn-color red':alerts[0].error!=0}"
```